# How to toggle Play and Pause with a UIBarbuttonItem

Tags: ios, swift3

Can anyone help me. I've search for my question and still can't figure out a solution, everything I found was not formatted in swift 3. Im trying to make a toggle Play and Pause out of a UIBarButtonItem. Whenever the play button is click I want it to play the file and at the same time change the UIBarButtonItem to pause and vise versa.

By the way I have embed in a navigation controller into my main view controller from the editor.

Here is my Code Snippet.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBOutlet weak var pausePlayBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareMusic()
    }

    func prepareMusic() {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SomeFileName", ofType: "TypeOfFile")! 
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func togglePausePlay(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if !audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.play()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.stop()  
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried the following.

First I started by creating play button and a pause button and adding them in my togglePausePlay func.

```
let playBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: nil)
let pauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause, target: self, action: nil)

@IBAction func togglePausePlay(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if !audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        audioPlayer.play()
        pausePlayBtn = playBtn
    } else {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        pausePlayBtn = pauseBtn
    }
}
```

The second thing I tried was this.

```
@IBAction func togglePausePlay(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if !audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        audioPlayer.play()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: nil)
    } else {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause, target: self, action: nil)
    }
}
```

This work at the start of the app, I would click the button for the first time and everything would work the button would change to pause and file would start. However when I tried to click it again nothing happens, button stays on pause and file still keeps playing until I stop the project.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: -: if !audioPlayer.isPlaying means if audio is not playing here you have to change the pause state of button but you didn't.You still doing THIS-: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause, target: self, action: nil)

Comment: Tushar Sharma I switch it to UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: nil) when !audioPlayer.isPlaying. However the problem still remains.

Comment: can you make that as first line and add audioPlayer.play() below it and try.Can you put a. Breakpoint and check it is going inside?

Comment: I guess u also need to check for button pause state with audioPlayer.isPlaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured out a solution for u and its working for me.

Here's the code i tried and its working. the buttonitem is changing on its click.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var playBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
var pauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem()

@IBOutlet var labelMusicState: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.playBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play , target: self, action: #selector(playBtnAction(sender:)))
        self.pauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause , target: self, action: #selector(pauseBtnAction(sender:)))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = playBtn
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func playBtnAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = pauseBtn
    self.labelMusicState.text = "Music is Playing"
}

func pauseBtnAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = playBtn
    self.labelMusicState.text = "Music Not Playing"
}

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul, it worked perfectly. Just wanted to know why it didn't work before. Was it because the UIBarButtonItem didn't have an action.

Comment: I guess your are right here. Also, the second method you were trying was not working as you were changing the right bar button on navigation controller and not current view. You can access your current view's right bar button item simple by self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.

Comment: Okay, Thank you again Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

In both the scenarios, you are trying to assign .play button to your existing button whenever the player starts playing music. It should be opposite. whenever the player starts playing music, your button should change to .pause mode and when the player stops playing music, the button should go to .play mode.

do the following modification:

```
    let playBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: nil)
    let pauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause, target: self, action: nil)

    @IBAction func togglePausePlay(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if !audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.play()
            pausePlayBtn = pauseBtn
        } else {
            audioPlayer.stop()
            pausePlayBtn = playBtn
           }
    }
```

You were doing the opposite due to which once the music starts playing, the button does not change its state from play to pause but remains in play state due to which the next time user presses the button, it plays the music and doesnt stop it.

Comment: Hey Rahul I made the modifications to my code but the pausePlayBtn still doesn't change when I click it. It still plays and stops the music but never changes it systemItem Style.